# Triangular grids

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic, coloring

Given two triangular grids as shown below. On each grid, what is the minimum number of vertices that should be marked so that each triangular cell has at least two marked vertices?

[image]

[image]

For the first diagram, one can try to either pr

There is a possible $17$ points method,but I don't know how to prove yet. Ove that at least $17$ points must be marked, or come up with a construction for which only $16$ points are needed.

Comment: The only way that I can imagine to prove that there is a 17 points solution is a demonstration: Show us 17 dots that work. For proving that 16 is not enough (if that is indeed the case), you either have to do something clever, or just check directly all possible combinations of 16 and show that none of them work.

Comment: I found this equivalent question easier to visualize: start with all dots marked, how many (at maximum) can you _unmark_ so that no two unmarked dots share the same triangle?  For the first diagram I can unmark $11$ giving a solution with $17$ marked dots, and for the second I can unmark $9$ giving a solution with $14$ marked dots.  I haven't quite figured out how to prove these are optimal.

Comment: I see the tag "contest-math".  What are the rules of the contest?  Are we allowed to give you hints?

Comment: Since I don't know how to link a picture
delete the point(1,1)(1,3)(1,6)(2,4)(3,1)(3,3)(3,6)(4,4)(5,1)(5,3)(5,6)
Turn the picture by 90 and do it